# ASP.NET MVC: OnKeyUp event for Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I wanna use the `OnKeyUp` event with AJAX in ASP.NET I have to do:

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions{... UpdateTargetId = "target"}) { 
   <div id = "target"></div>
   @Html.TextBox ("TextField","", new {@OnKeyUp = "TriggerFunction()"}
   <input type="submit" id = "button" style = "display:none"/>
}
```

Then in JQuery

```
  function TriggerFunction(){
      $("#button").trigger("click")
  }
```

Although this works, I'm curious does ASP.NET MVC have any built in feature to do this? I mean trigger the `BeginForm` method based on different events like `OnKeyUp` or `OnChanged`?

Comment: No, because at this point the view has been sent to the browser, so you need to use javascript to handle client side events

Comment: One more build in feature is Ajax.ActionLink but it isn't suits your demands.